# ST-Links convert Feature Class to DB Table error

Tags: postgis, shapefile, arcgis-10.1, geometry, st-links

I'm using ArcMap with the ST-Links SpatialKit Conversion tool to convert a Feature Class to a DB Table. But I'm getting an error: ERROR: 42601: type modifier is not allowed for type "geometry".

I can't seem to find anything on that error.

Feature Class (shapefile)

```
Geometry Type : Polygon
Projected Coordinate System : WGS_1984_UTM_Zone_21S
Projection : Traverse_Mercator
Geographic Coordinate System : GCS_WGS_1984
```

DB

```
PostgreSQL 8.3
Postgis 1.5
```

Any ideas? I have other tables in the DB that were generated with Quantum GIS. I also can't open the other spacial tables on ArcMap correctly. In Quantum GIS I have no problems. But I need to work with ArcGIS.

Thanks,

Comment: The last version should solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with this software so I downloaded it to have a look.  A couple of things:

1. Do you have the latest version of this software?
2. Do you have a paid license for this software?  If so, perhaps the developers have an answer for you.
3. Maybe you could try changing the spatial type at the bottom right of the conversion dialog box.  See below:

[image]